# sql remove duplicate record while using join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a following table structure which can't be change.

[image]

I'm trying to join these table and want to avoid duplicate records as well.

```
 select p.ProductId,p.ProductName,inv.Details from Products p
inner join Inventory inv on(p.ProductId = inv.ProductId)
```

here is [**SqlFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/502f0/2/0).

Comment: Duplicated records can be removed with DISTINCT, but your rows aren't duplicated. So you'll need to change what you select so you can DISTINCT it.

Comment: What is your expected output??

Comment: Please mention your expected output

Comment: @Gone: ProductId should be unique.

Comment: Do you want `join`?? As you can use `subquery` for it

Comment: @Gone: I have to use Join since there are other query too.

Comment: @AshwiniVerma Please state your expected output .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From sqlserver 2008+ you can use cross apply.

With cross apply you can make a join inside the subselect as demonstrated here. With top 1 you get maximum 1 row from table Inventory. It will also be possible to add an 'order by' statement to the subselect. However that seems out of scope for your question.

```
select p.ProductId,p.ProductName,x.Details 
from Products p
cross apply
(SELECT top 1 inv.Details FROM Inventory inv WHERE p.ProductId = inv.ProductId) x
```

Comment: from the table Inventory, it's ok if I get top 1 record. your both query still display duplicate productid. query should display unique productid no matter which detail it takes from inventory table.

Comment: @AshwiniVerma the bottom example should not show duplicate productid

Comment: please run your query in Sqlfiddle which I linked. It does show duplicate.

Comment: @AshwiniVerma you are right. I misunderstood the question. I changed my answer now. If you include data and expected result in your question next time it is easier to solve it.

Comment: please add more explanation to your answer

Comment: @Philip added explanation, I hope you find it useful

Comment: @AshwiniVerma When you say Duplicate what exactly you mean by that and if you could just post a scenario, expected output .

Answer (score 1):

You can use row_number function to remove duplicates

```
   WITH New_Inventory AS
    (
        SELECT Productid, Details,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition by Productid ORDER BY details) AS RowNumber
        FROM Products
    ) 
    select p.ProductId,p.ProductName,inv.Details from Products p
    inner join New_Inventory inv on(p.ProductId = inv.ProductId)
    where RowNumber = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select p.ProductId,p.ProductName 
,(select top 1 inv.Details from  Inventory inv where (p.ProductId = inv.ProductId))Details
from Products p
```

or

```
select * from 
(
select p.ProductId,p.ProductName,inv.Details
,ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by p.productid order by p.productid)rn from Products p
inner join Inventory inv on(p.ProductId = inv.ProductId)
)t4 
where rn=1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with cte as 
(select p.ProductId,p.ProductName,inv.Details,
RoW_Number() OVER(Partition by  p.ProductId,p.ProductName,inv.Details
                  Order by p.ProductId,p.ProductName,inv.Details) rn
 from Products p
inner join Inventory inv on(p.ProductId = inv.ProductId))

select ProductId,ProductName,Details from cte where rn = 1
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/502f0/53)